# Composer update trouble

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm using laravel + composer . I'm loading way/generators package and when I run composer update give me this error:

> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 67108864 bytes) in
>   phar:///usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.0.0-alpha8/libexec/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php
>   on line 170

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think, This is because composer update has used all the memory.

```
php -d memory_limit=1G /usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.0.0-alpha8/libexec/composer.phar update
```

This works for me on a mac.

Also check out to use composer install.

Comment: I can confirm this also works for me on a CentOS 5.6 VM.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a server with less amount of RAM like 512MB you will need to create swap memory. Here is how you do it on ubuntu

```
touch swap.img
chmod 600 swap.img
```

Using 1GB for swap

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.img bs=1024k count=1000
mkswap /var/swap.img
swapon /var/swap.img
```

Here is the full article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-virtual-memory-swap-file-on-a-vps

Answer (score 1):

I was having problem to install laravel with composer.
Original command was:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

And Error message was:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.0.0-alpha8/libexec/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 170
```

Following command should work:

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G /usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.0.0-alpha8/libexec/composer.phar global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I encountered the same problem and manage to solve by halting the Apache and MySQL service and then proceeding to install the laravel application via composer.

The `sudo service stop apache2`  followed by `sudo service stop mysql stop` this in turn killed the application that were consuming memory I then proceeded to install the Laravel via the normal composer command once done I just restarted the service and everything was fine.

Comment: none of the other solutions but this worked for me. I don't know what is going on in my memory but it seems to be the case that apache and mysql are consuming a so much memory that the swap and the memory are both full. Stopping worked great.

Comment: @steven what spec is your current server running  may be increasing the RAM size might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, after read this post: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898

Thank you to "Dynom, commented on Jul 4, 2013"

> Needing 512MiB RAM for a package-manager is already a bit much, but I
>   also exceed it. The interesting part is that I exceed 512 MiB RAM (up
>   to around 800 MiB RAM according to my process output) when I use my
>   private Satis repository (which is actually just a cache for all
>   Github public repositories). I do not exceed it otherwise. Just by
>   adding my satis repository, composer consumes almost 400 MiB more RAM
>
> To all the others raising their PHP CLI memory_limit globally, I
>   recommend against that. Instead I suggest to put it in the command
>   line, like so:

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G {composer location} update
```

Example:

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/composer.phar update
```

> Otherwise you could potentially miss certain unintended memory related
>   behaviour in your own work.

Tested on: Debian version 6

Comment: Not only for `update` command. Of course, if you have problem with Memory you need to use `php -dmemory_limit` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the last version of composer? I've fixed that problem with a simple update:

```
sudo composer self-update
```